# Openchange installation error

Tags: samba4

I'm trying to install sogo with openchange activated on ubuntu 14.04
It's a fresh install.

I have installed ubuntu with samba, and after login i have upgrated samba to samba 4 version

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade samba
```

I have tested the samba configuration with

```
smbclient -L localhost -U%
```

I shows me the desired output.

Then I have installed sogo and configured it with my mail server. Until there everything works fine.
I'm loggin successfully to `sogo` and I have all mails users.

```
# apt-get install mysql-server
# apt-get install apache2 php5
# a2enmod proxy; a2enmod proxy_http; a2enmod headers; a2enmod rewrite; a2dismod reqtimeout; a2enmod proxy_balancer;
# service apache2 restart
# apt-get install sogo sogo-activesync sope4.9-gdl1-mysql
```

Configuration of samba4 and installation of openchange

```
# cd /etc/samba/
# mv smb.conf smb.conf.orig
# mv /var/lib/samba/private/ /var/lib/samba/private.back

# samba-tool domain provision --interactive

Realm [SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM]: 
 Domain [SUBDOMAIN]: 
 Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]: 
 DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE) [SAMBA_INTERNAL]: 
 DNS forwarder IP address (write 'none' to disable forwarding) [IP_ADDRESS_OF_MY_DNS_SERVER]: 
Administrator password: 
Retype password: 

..............


Server Role:           active directory domain controller
Hostname:              HOSTNAMLE
NetBIOS Domain:        SUBDOMAIN
DNS Domain:            subdomain.domain.com
DOMAIN SID:            S-1-5-21-1239474844-1241229800-1059178920



# samba-tool user setexpiry Administrator --noexpiry
# vim /etc/resolv.conf
        nameserver 127.0.0.1
        domain subdomain.domain.com
        search subdomain.domain.com
# service smbd restart
# service nmbd restart

# apt-get install openchangeserver sogo-openchange openchangeproxy openchange-ocsmanager openchange-rpcproxy python-mysqldb
```

Then I have followed the openchnage configuration from this link : [Configuring the Server](http://www.openchange.org/cookbook/configuring.html)

```
    # export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    # samba-tool user add openuser 'openuser1!'

User 'openuser' created successfully

# vim /etc/samba/smb.conf
    ### Configuration required by OpenChange server ###
    dcerpc endpoint servers = +epmapper, +mapiproxy, +dnsserver
    dcerpc_mapiproxy:server = true
    dcerpc_mapiproxy:interfaces = exchange_emsmdb, exchange_nsp, exchange_ds_rfr

    dsdb:schema update allowed = true
    ### Configuration required by OpenChange server ###

# service smbd restart
# service nmbd restart

# openchange_provision --standalone
NOTE: This operation can take several minutes
[+] Step 1: Register Exchange OIDs
[+] Step 2: Add Exchange attributes to Samba schema
[+] Step 3: Add Exchange auxiliary classes to Samba schema
[+] Step 4: Add Exchange objectCategory to Samba schema
[+] Step 5: Add Exchange containers to Samba schema
[+] Step 6: Add Exchange *sub* containers to Samba schema
[+] Step 7: Add Exchange CfgProtocol subcontainers to Samba schema
[+] Step 8: Add Exchange mailGateway subcontainers to Samba schema
[+] Step 9: Add Exchange classes to Samba schema
[+] Step 10: Add possSuperior attributes to Exchange classes
[+] Step 11: Extend existing Samba classes and attributes
[+] Step 12: Generic Exchange configuration objects
[+] Step 13: Exchange Organization objects
[+] Step 14: Update generic Exchange configuration objects
[SUCCESS] Done!
[+] Step 1: Exchange Samba registration
[SUCCESS] Done!
[+] Step 1: Register Exchange Samba as the main server
[SUCCESS] Done!




# openchange_provision --openchangedb
Setting up openchange db
    * Public Folder Root                      : 0x0100000000000001 (72057594037927937)
    * IPM_SUBTREE                             : 0x0200000000000001 (144115188075855873)
    * NON_IPM_SUBTREE                         : 0x0300000000000001 (216172782113783809)
    * EFORMS REGISTRY                         : 0x0400000000000001 (288230376151711745)
    * OFFLINE ADDRESS BOOK                    : 0x0500000000000001 (360287970189639681)
    * /o=First Organization/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address Book: 0x0600000000000001 (432345564227567617)
    * SCHEDULE+ FREE BUSY                     : 0x0700000000000001 (504403158265495553)
    * EX:/o=First Organization/ou=First Administrative Group: 0x0800000000000001 (576460752303423489)
    * Events Root                             : 0x0900000000000001 (648518346341351425)
```

I have created the openchange database and created the openchnagemysql user successfully.

```
# vim /etc/samba/smb.conf
    mapistore:namedproperties = mysql
    namedproperties:mysql_user = openchangemysql
    namedproperties:mysql_pass = openchangemysqlpass
    namedproperties:mysql_host = localhost
    namedproperties:mysql_db = openchange

    mapistore:indexing_backend = mysql://openchangemysql:openchangemysqlpass$@localhost/openchange
    mapiproxy:openchangedb = mysql://openchangemysql:openchangemysqlpass$@localhost/openchange  

# openchange_newuser --create openuser
[+] User openuser extended and enabled
root@sogochange:~# openchange_newuser --create Administrator
[+] User Administrator extended and enabled
```

The problem is there

```
# samba -d3 -i -M single
lpcfg_load: refreshing parameters from /etc/samba/smb.conf
samba version 4.3.8-Ubuntu started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2015
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
NTPTR backend 'simple_ldb'
NTVFS backend 'default' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'posix' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'unixuid' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'unixuid' for type 3 registered
NTVFS backend 'unixuid' for type 2 registered
NTVFS backend 'cifs' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'smb2' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'simple' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'cifsposix' for type 1 registered
NTVFS backend 'default' for type 3 registered
NTVFS backend 'default' for type 2 registered
NTVFS backend 'nbench' for type 1 registered
PROCESS_MODEL 'single' registered
PROCESS_MODEL 'standard' registered
AUTH backend 'sam' registered
AUTH backend 'sam_ignoredomain' registered
AUTH backend 'anonymous' registered
AUTH backend 'winbind' registered
AUTH backend 'winbind_wbclient' registered
AUTH backend 'name_to_ntstatus' registered
AUTH backend 'unix' registered
SHARE backend [classic] registered.
ldb_wrap open of privilege.ldb
samba: using 'single' process model
DCERPC endpoint server 'rpcecho' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'epmapper' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'remote' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'srvsvc' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'wkssvc' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'unixinfo' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'samr' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'winreg' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'netlogon' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'dssetup' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'lsarpc' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'backupkey' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'spoolss' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'drsuapi' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'browser' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'eventlog6' registered
DCERPC endpoint server 'dnsserver' registered
dcesrv_init_context: failed to find endpoint server = 'mapiproxy'
task_server_terminate: [Failed to startup dcerpc server task]
/usr/sbin/smbd: smbd version 4.3.8-Ubuntu started.
/usr/sbin/smbd: Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2015
samba_terminate: Failed to startup dcerpc server task
```

My error is there

```
  dcesrv_init_context: failed to find endpoint server = 'mapiproxy'
  task_server_terminate: [Failed to startup dcerpc server task]
  /usr/sbin/smbd: smbd version 4.3.8-Ubuntu started.
  /usr/sbin/smbd: Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2015
  samba_terminate: Failed to startup dcerpc server task
```

It should be like that : [Output: Starting OpenChange with Samba 4.0.0-rc5 server](http://www.openchange.org/cookbook/configuration/output-samba-4.0.0-rc5.html)

I'm blocked for two days.
I have carefully followed the steps.
I have also few questions :
    Should I configure the computers with the domain (AD / samba) to use outlook ?
    How to test outlook connection to my mail server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the OpenChange modules in the same location that you have Samba installed, otherwise Samba won't be able to find the OpenChange modules. Passing --prefix=/usr to OpenChange's configure should do this.

Note that building OpenChange against the system version of Samba is more likely to be problematic, as it is very tightly coupled to Samba. You're more likely to have success if you build Samba from source (using "make samba4" from the OpenChange directory).